# Divide application into modules

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2, appointment

Should I divide the app into separate modules, for example:

- Admin actually everthing can be here
- module calendar
- module messages <- all comunication with clients
- etc..

I am wondering because even if I dive app into smaller modules there no chance that if I swith off for example messages that whole aplication will work, because if the first appointment is made the message is being send, and I am using there a model form messages.

I think that modules should be totaly separate, and one can work without another. Is it the convention of modules? On the other hand if I will not divide it It could be quite big module Admin and a bit messy. Offcourse there is way to achieve that, I could replicate the code so that ecah module colud work alone. But replication code? I don't think it's a good idea.

I know my question is a bit theoretical but I want learn good practice I have that question all the time in the back of my head .Should I create new module or just another controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesnot matter how many module you have, but keep your business logic out of controller, as services/model/repositories, so that you can access it from any controller.

Generally Devs. build "admin" , "application", "front" module.
But it is not limited here.

Modules are just for organising your files,code, logic so that your fellow developer can easily follow.

Create a new module if you think a lot of things is going for that and it is smething special.

```
For Ex:
suppose you have two module "Admin", "Application".
You can create a third module "Basic", containg logic/modal/services for both "admin", "application".
```

see module structure strategy on ZF page, https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-modulemanager/intro/

I think it will more helpfull to understanding you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Reply. So in general you are say I schould not care some much that every module scholud be totaly Independent. Earlier I was plaing a lot with magento and wroting some modules maybe that why was convinced that every module schoud be intependet.

Comment: Module may be independent Or may be dependent on some module, as per requirement, as your "Admin" module may be independent from "Front" module , but may be dependent on some other module.

Comment: Admin is admin front is front, but application? What it should be in there. lets say we have very simple cms based on zend. eg. pages, categories, Admin will be for managing pages and categories/ front for diplaying them and application any other extra functionality for example media album or something ?

Comment: In simple way, when application load, all module configured at "application.module.php" is loaded, and when you open front-end(UI) pages, you would not like to load extra contents of "Admin" module, which is not required for front UI user, so here independent module should be there.

Comment: suppose your system have "crons" for sending email/updating something, and you can put these type of codes/logic on application module.

Comment: Front is always dependent in my applications because for example I have a model PagesTable and this table model has method getpagebyid which is used both in admin for editing the current page (geting the content and passing to forms) and in frontend geting the content to display the content to final user using the same model. This is the same scenerio which I described in my question. Should i duplicate PagesTable in front module and admin module?

Comment: You should consider to create an additional module for this, code should not be duplicate, the all common code add to this new module,